# Get old value from CComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, ccombobox

1. User changes the value in a `CComboBox`.
2. The function `OnCbnSelchangeXXX()` is called.

Can I retrieve the old `CComboBox´s` old value in the function?

Comment: To the moderators: I don't understand what happened here. Someone answered this question a while ago and I commented on that answer. Now that I hit F5 in my browser to refresh the page and see if he had answered my comment neither the answer nor my comment are there. A bug? Or was the answer and my comment removed?

Comment: This answer was deleted by the owner, because he decided that it was incorrect (and it was incorrect indeed).

Comment: Regarding your question - this is impossible, just keep old selection in some variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that to me :)